# Bullet raises 'USE eager loading detected' error when create single record with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have following models:

**preference.rb**

```
class Preference < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :preferences_ingredients, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :prohibited_ingredients, through: :preferences_ingredients, source: :ingredient
```

**ingredient**

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category, class_name: :IngredientCategory

  has_many :preferences_ingredients, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :preferences, through: :preferences_ingredients
```

And when Im trying to create preference with prohibited_ingredient_ids:

```
input = { prohibited_ingredient_ids: ['e6a3b97f-c783-4a1d-8dcd-f3b88059fd6b'], ... }

object_class.create!(input)
```

I got bullet error:

```
     Bullet::Notification::UnoptimizedQueryError:
       user: ruslan
       POST /preferences
       USE eager loading detected
         Ingredient => [:category]
         Add to your query: .includes([:category])
```

Can anyone help me to understand what am I doing wrong, and how to fix this, please?